# How much is scripted/choreographed in Grease?

Tags: production, musical, grease

There are many little things in the movie *Grease* that make me wonder what was choreographed, what was accidental, what was just left in to avoid doing a re-take, or what was left up to the performers to improvize?

For example, at [3:00 of this clip of *Beauty School Dropout*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0TOxhzAm7fY&t=2m58s), Stockard Channing as Rizzo stops singing, looks to her left, then resumes singing.

At [1:32 of this clip of *Summer Nights*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZW0DfsCzfq4&t=1m28s) Frenchy is handed a juice box that she doesn't do anything of significance with for the rest of the song.

In this movie how much of these little details are choreographed? How much is accidental? Or, if that is too broad: what about these two specific examples?

Comment: I imagine many of these are accidental (such as the Rizzo example) and others are spur of the moment items that fit into other more choreographed items. Having been in several plays, I can say that not every single action of every character is choreographed, but every one has a general idea of what to do and when to do it, and the rest is kind of up to the actor.